# JS Foreach Alternative (timeout) for Queue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on the "Approve All" button. The process here is when I click "Approve All," each individual "Approve" button will be triggered as "click" all at once, and then it will send `POST` requests to the controller. However, when I clicked `Approve All` button, there was a race condition causing the controller returns `Error 500: Internal server error`. I have tried using JS `setTimeout()` with value `1500*iter`, but when the iterator gets higher, for example at `i = 100`, then it would take `1500*100 => 150000ms (150s)`. I hope that explains the problem clearly. Is there a way to prevent such a case?

Here is my code, I'm using JQuery:

```
let inspection = $this.parents("li").find("ul button.approve"); // this will get all 'approve' button to be clicked at once
inspection.each((i,e)=>{ 
    (function () {
        setTimeout(function () { 
            $(e).data("note",r);
            $(e).click();
        }, 1500 * i); // this acts like a queue, but when i > 100, it takes even longer to send POST requests.
    })(this,i,e,r);
});

// then, each iteration will send a POST request to the controller.

$("#data-inspection ul button.approve").on("click", function() {
    // send POST requests
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What data is posted when a `button.approve` is clicked? It would be easily collected into an array then sent once.

Comment: zer00ne's comment is a much more elegant approach than what's in my answer

Comment: @zer00ne the `data` is either "approve" or "reject." Yes, your solution can also be the alternative, I'll give it a try. Thank you!

Comment: In the case where your server can't be changed and can only accept single items, then you should use a jQuery ajax *queue*.  There's numerous existing solutions, but essentially you create an array of ajax requests (without firing them) then fire the first - when it completes (`.done()`) fire the next one on the queue, until the queue is empty.

Answer (score 0):

That 500 error may also be the server crashing from being unable to process all the requests simultaneously.

What I'd recommend is using an event-driven approach instead of `setTimeout`. Your 1500ms is basically a guess - you don't know whether clicks will happen too quickly, or if you'll leave users waiting unnecessarily.

I'll demonstrate without jQuery how to do it, and leave the jQuery implementation up to you:

```js
// use a .js- class to target buttons your buttons directly,
// simplifying your selectors, and making them DOM agnostic
const buttonEls = document.querySelectorAll('.js-my-button'); 
const buttonsContainer = document.querySelector('.js-buttons-container');
const startRequestsEvent = new CustomEvent('customrequestsuccess');
// convert the DOMCollection to an array when passing it in
const handleRequestSuccess = dispatchNextClickFactory([...buttonEls]);

buttonsContainer.addEventListener('click', handleButtonClick);
buttonsContainer.addEventListener(
  'customrequestsuccess',
  handleRequestSuccess
);

// start the requests by dispatching the event buttonsContainer
// is listening for
buttonsContainer.dispatchEvent(startRequestsEvent);

// This function is a closure:
//   - it accepts an argument
//   - it returns a new function (the actual event listener)
//   - the returned function has access to the variables defined
//     in its outer scope
// Note that we don't care what elements are passed in - all we
// know is that we have a list of elements
function dispatchNextClickFactory(elements) {
  let pendingElements = [...elements];

  function dispatchNextClick() {
    // get the first element that hasn't been clicked
    const element = pendingElements.find(Boolean);

    if (element) {
      const clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true});

      // dispatch a click on the element
      element.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);

      // remove the element from the pending elements
      pendingElements = pendingElements.filter((_, i) => i > 0);
    }
  }

  return dispatchNextClick;
}

// use event delegation to mitigate adding n number of listeners to 
// n number of buttons - attach to a common parent
function handleButtonClick(event => {
  const {target} = event

  if (target.classList.contains('js-my-button')) {
    fetch(myUrl)
      .then(() => {
        // dispatch event to DOM indicating request is complete when the
        // request succeeds
        const completeEvent = new CustomEvent('customrequestsuccess');
    
        target.dispatchEvent(completeEvent);
      })
  }
})
```

There are a number of improvements that can be made here, but the main ideas here are that:

- one should avoid magic numbers - we don't know how slowly or quickly requests are going to be processed
- requests are asynchronous - we can determine explicitly when they succeed or fail
- DOM events are powerful

  - when a DOM event is handled, we do something with the event
  - when some event happens that we want other things to know about, we can dispatch custom events. We can attach as many handlers to as many elements as we want for each event we dispatch - it's just an event, and any element may do anything with that event. e.g. we could make every element in the DOM flash if we wanted to by attaching a listener to every element for a specific event

Note: this code is untested